# Cmake sub_directory, libs dependencies needed to be build

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I would like to add libraries to my current project.
The idea was to do something like this :

```
if(build_libs)
    add_subdirectory(libs1)
    add_subdirectory(libs2)
    add_subdirectory(libs3)
    add_subdirectory(libs4)
endif()
```

But, libs2 need generated files/lib from libs1 after the build. There is a cmake verification/find from libs2 finding libs1.
How can I enforce libs1 to be build before adding subdir libs2 ?
Same for libs3->2, libs4->3

Comment: "How can I enforce libs1 to be build before adding subdir libs2?" - Instead of adding `libs1` via `add_subdirectory()`, build (and, probably, install) it with [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/execute_process.html). Commands passed to `execute_process` are performed immediately, so futher `find_*` commands will see all produced files.

Comment: ... if `lib2` depends on (some) build artifacts of `lib1` (which can be obtained from the build directory), just use `add_dependency(lib2 lib1)` to establish inter-target dependencies... CMake would take care of build order...

Comment: We finally decided to not use CmakeFiles from libs and rewrite it. Too much useless stuff in it.

Both of your answers are correct.